# Working with Scriptable Objects: Keep getting "No suitable method found to override"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently teaching myself on proper use of Scriptable Objects and how to get them to communicate with other scripts. Getting the error "No suitable method found to override". Done my own research and it is always because of a typo or because something was not exactly the same. I dont see either of those problems in my script. It is so basic I have looked over it like 20 times.

```
 public class DamageFormula : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public int Attack;
        public int Power;
        public int Damage;

        // Start is called before the first frame update
        public void Start()
        {
            Power = 0;
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            CalculateDamage(Attack, Power);
        }

        void CalculateDamage(int Attack, int Power)
        {
            Damage = Attack * Power;
        }
    }
```

Here is base class for skill:

```
public abstract class BaseSkills : ScriptableObject
{
    public int Power;

    public abstract void Start(GameObject BattleManager);
}
```

Here is the first skill: Problem is at public override void Start (Gameobject BattleManager)

```
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Skills/HeadButt")]
public class HeadButt : ScriptableObject
{
    public int Power = 30;

    private DamageFormula damageFormula;

    public override void Start(GameObject BattleManager)
    {
        damageFormula = BattleManager.GetComponent<DamageFormula>();
        damageFormula.Start();
        damageFormula.Power = Power;
    }

}
```

What is the problem? What does it want me to do?

Comment: Should not your class derive from BaseSkill?

Comment: *eyeroll* Thank you so much...*loud sign*